# Making Javascript Variables...not variables

Tags: javascript

Possibly a silly question, and i'm not sure how to phrase it.

I have an array in a function and I want put it through a loop  print the text, not the variable.  I've just starting banging my head on this, but whats really getting me is how to only print lets say the "category" and value if the value is not empty.  Here's and example to show,  The outcome i'm looking for is "u =1 and x = 1 AND z = 3".  If anyone could point me in the write direction, it would be most helpful.

```
(categories called from multiple selection menus in text)
s=
t=
u=1
v=
w=
x=1
y=
z=3
function example(s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) {

    selection=[s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z];
    for (var i=0;;i++)
    {
        if (!selection[i]) {
            selection="";
        }
        else
        {
            selection= selection + 
        };
    }
}
```

The outcome i'm looking for is
"u =1 and x = 1 AND z = 3"

Comment: There are so many problems with this code I don't know where to begin...

Comment: im seeing lots of syntax errors u sure this is ur code

Comment: Uhh, first of all, your loop is infinite, is it not? That's a problem...second of all, you didn't post the full code. You're missing some semicolons. (Like a lot). And I don't know where you're calling the functions.

Comment: I understand what you're asking for (though with so many syntax errors perhaps I'm wrong), and the original variable name is not preserved so you can't tell JS to *look up the name of the variable holding the value*.

Comment: Use an array or an object instead of so many variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide semi functional code since I am not at my work desk. Assuming your variables are declared as parameters or as plain variables somewhere. You can declare a the names of variables as an array, loop over the array and use the eval function to evaluate their value

```
selection=["s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];
output = "";
    for (var i=0; i < selection.length; i++)
    {
        value = eval(selection[i]);
        if (value==""){
           //nothing to do
         }
        else
        {
          output += selection[i] + "=" + value; 
        };
     }
```

Comment: holy cow, thanks so much for seeing through my horrid question.  This puts me much closer to what I need to do....now I just need to figure out how to put a "AND" between values (but not after the last).  This really teaches me alot.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to enumerate all fields manualy, you can construct object with fields, and then iterate over it keys:

```
function example(s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z){
    var selection = {
        s: s,
        t: t,
        u: u,
        v: v,
        w: w,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        z: z
    };
    var out = "";
    for(var i in selection){
        if(selection[i]){
        if(!out){
            out += " "; // insert space between values
        }
        out += i + '=' + selection[i];
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an indexed array (aka. object) to print values with their name.

```
var selection = {"s": s, "t": t, "u": u, "v": v, "w": w, "x": x, "y": y, "z": z};
for (var i in selection)
    document.write(i + " = " + selection[i]);
```